Tensorflow executes slow on GPU - retracing issue?
I am trying to develop a transformer sequence to vector model but encounter performance issues.
I am working with a Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB. Whenever the model encounters an unseen sequence length, the (training-) step takes much longer. I assume this is due to the tracing algorithm, creating the tensorflow graph. However, I do not get any retracing warnings or so. I know there is the @tf.function(reduce_retracing=True) decorator, but I would have to rewrite the MultiHeadAttention class from scratch and decorate every function.
I am using tensorflow Version 2.17.0.
Here is code for replication. In this snippet I have a small exemplary network, training on 100 samples. The first 10 batches have varying shapes and take around 1.5 seconds per batch. The last 90 batches have similar shapes, taking 0.002 seconds per batch.
How to approach this issue?
import datetime
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# only use the first gpu
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
assert gpus, "no gpus found"
gpu=gpus[1]
tf.config.set_visible_devices([gpu], "GPU")
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

nclasses = 3
d_model = 8


# A custom Data Generator, creating random samples
class DG(keras.utils.PyDataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nSamplesWithAlternatingShapes = 10
        super().__init__()
        self.last=datetime.datetime.now()

    def __len__(self):
        return 100

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        n = self.nSamplesWithAlternatingShapes
        if index < self.nSamplesWithAlternatingShapes:
            n = index
        x = np.random.random((32, n + 10, d_model))
        y = np.random.random((32, nclasses))
        y = np.argmax(y, axis=1)
        y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=nclasses)
        now=datetime.datetime.now()
        print(f"\n{round((now-self.last).total_seconds(), ndigits=3)} secs elapsed")
        self.last=now
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(x), y

# A Test layer, incorporating a MultiHeadAttention Layer
class TestLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # some multi head attention
        self.mha = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=1, value_dim=d_model, key_dim=d_model, dropout=0.3
        )
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nclasses, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.mha(x, x, x)
        pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_last")(x)
        fin = self.dense(pool)
        return fin


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # The first dimension is the sequence dimension
    input = tf.keras.layers.Input((None, d_model), name="test", dtype=np.float32)
    output = TestLayer()(input)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=output)
    model.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name="OA")],
    )
    
    model.fit(DG(), shuffle=False)
    
    print("done")


I also asked on github (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/20369).
It seems there is no simple solution to this problem, only workarounds. XLA-compilation would mean too much coding in my case, as this has to be implemented at very low abstraction level.
Using buckets is something I already tried with somewhat feasible results and will be my go to approach:
I pad the flexible input dimension to have a size, of a multiple of 10. Thus, I am reducing the retracing by a factor of 10 times, making the GPU somewhat feasible.
